# Why is JSON.parse so picky with quotes?

Tags: javascript, json, syntax

Basically, I am trying to create an object like this by providing a string to JSON.parse():

```
a = {x:1} 
// -> Object {x: 1}
```

Intuitively I tried:

```
a = JSON.parse('{x:1}')
// -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token x
```

After some fiddling I figured out:

```
a = JSON.parse('{"x":1}')
// -> Object {x: 1}
```

But then I accidentally changed the syntax and bonus confusion kicked in:

```
a = JSON.parse("{'x':1}")
//-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

---

So now I am looking for an explanation why

1. one **must** to quote the property name
2. the implementation accepts single quotes, but fails on double quotes

Comment: Because that's what the spec says?

Comment: [JSON rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)

Comment: But is there a reason for that?

Comment: It keeps the parsing rules simple.

Comment: specifications save lives

Comment: This is also why you should never write JSON by hand.

Comment: "the implementation accepts single quotes, but fails on double quotes": it's the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for confusion seems to be the difference between JSON and JavaScript objects.

---

**JSON** (JavaScript Object Notation) is a data format meant to allow data exchange in a simple format. That is the reason why there is one valid syntax only. It makes parsing much easier. You can find more information on the [JSON website](http://json.org).

Some notes about JSON:

- Keys must be quoted with `"`
- Values might be strings, numbers, objects, arrays, booleans or "null"
- String values must be quoted with `"`

---

[**JavaScript objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) on the other hand are related to JSON (obviously), but not identical. Valid JSON is also a valid JavaScript object. The other way around, however, is not.

For example:

- keys and values can be quoted with `"` or `'`
- keys do not always have to be quoted
- values might be functions or JavaScript objects

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, because that's what the JSON spec specifies. The reason AFAIK is that JSON is meant to be a *data interchange* format (language agnostic). Many languages, even those with hash literals, do not allow unquoted strings as hash table keys.

Comment: "Many languages, even those with hash literals, do not allow unquoted strings as hash table keys." — That's not relevant. It's a data interchange format, not something designed to be evaluated as Joe Random Programming Language Code. XML is also language agnostic and allows single or double quoted attribute names.

Comment: Fair enough, but it has to be *readable* by Joe Random programmer

Comment: Totally get it. But shouldn't javascript handle "somestring" in the same way it does 'somestring' ?

Comment: @AndreLung — What does JavaScript have to do with it?

Comment: 'javascript' does. but while JSON is valid javascript, javascript is not necessarily valid JSON

Comment: @Quentin I am using Javascript. As far as I understand (and see in the chrome console) both 'xyz' and "xyz" are turned to the same strings ("{x}" === '{x}' -> true). When I provide a string paramter to a function, shouldn't the quoting style be irrelevant?

Comment: @AndreLung — No. The `JSON.parse` function expects the string to consist of JSON data not JavaScript data.

Comment: please see my comment above: Javascript is not necessarily JSON. Just to pick one example, this is valid javascript but not valid JSON: `{"foo": function(){return 2;}}`

Comment: So, instead of being handled by Javascript, the parameter (the JSON data) is instantly handed to an implementation in another language? I always imagined that the parameter would at least be parsed to a string. (Sorry for bugging around. Just had problems understanding that)

Comment: The word 'parse' gets bandied about a lot, but it has a fairly precise definition. `JSON.parse` in javascript does not read the passed-in string as javascript code directly, it parses it according to the formal grammatic rules of the JSON specification. It converts it to symbolic tokens, which are then interpreted as javascript data structures. But that first step requires the string to be in accordance with the grammatical rules of JSON. If you want to 'parse' a string of arbitrary javascript, use `eval()` (but I don't recommend it)